# An optimal subspace projection problem

Tags: np-hardness, approximation-algorithms, linear-algebra, approximation-hardness, high-dimensional-geometry

Suppose we have a $k$-dimensional subspace $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by a basis $\{v_1,\cdots,v_k\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$, find an index set $I\subset [n]$ with $|I|=m$ where $k\le m\le n$, such that
$$\max_{v\in V}\frac{||v||_2}{||v_I||_2}$$
is minimum, where $v_I\in \mathbb{R}^m$ is the projection of $v$ to the coordinates indexed by $I$.

My question is:

1. Is this problem NP-hard?
2. If $k$ is a constant, $m$ can be unbounded, is this problem still NP-hard?
3. If it is NP-hard, what is the best (or any) approximate ratio we can achieve?

Any references in the literature will also be welcome.

---

**Edit:** This problem is equivalent to the following submatrix selection problem: let $V$ be a $k\times n$ matrix such that the row vectors of $V$ are orthonormal, find a submatrix $V'$ of $V$ by selecting $m$ columns from $V$, such that
$$\sigma_{\min}(V')\text{ is maximum},$$
where $\sigma_{\min}$ is the smallest singular value. Follows are (partial) answers to the question:

1. question 1 is NP-hard even for $k=m$, (slightly modified) reduction from X3C as in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397509004101)
2. question 2 is still open. (I would be appropriated if one could provide any references)
3. For approximation, one can achieve the approximation ratio of
   $$\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\right)^2}{\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{n}{m}}\right)^2},$$by [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.0127.pdf), this gives a $\Omega\left(\frac{\epsilon m}{m+n}\right)$ bound for $m\ge (1+\epsilon)k$. When $m=k$, one can achieve $\Omega\left(\frac{1}{k(1+\epsilon)}\right)$ bound for any $\epsilon>0$, by using a local search algorithm by [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8462626).
4. The hardness of approximation is unknown, even for $m=k$.

Comment: When you say "projection to the coordinates indexed by $I$", you mean coordinates of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @usul yes, it is.

Comment: Is this equivalent to the following problem?  Given a $k$-dimensional sphere $S_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, find an index set $I$ of size $m$ so that the projection of $S_k$ onto $\mathbb{R}^n_I$ has minimum diameter, where $\mathbb{R}^n_I$ is the linear subspace spanned by the $m$ axes with coordinate indices in $I$.

Comment: @NealYoung Yes, but what I need here is actually to make the smallest principal axes of the projected ellipsoid to be maximum.

Comment: Isn't that the same in the following sense (keeping in mind that we restrict to $v$ with $\|v\|_2=1$)? $J$ minimizes the diameter of the projection of $S_k$ onto $\mathbb{R}^n_J$ if and only if $I = [n]\setminus J$ maximizes the length of the smallest principal axis of the projection of $S_k$ onto $\mathbb{R}^n_I$.